# Android Native to JavaScript Communication through cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, web-applications

I am working on `Android cordova` hybrid application and looking now the best way to call javascript function from android native and to get the result also.

I am able to call javascript function from `loadUrl("Javascript:someFunction()")` of `CordovaWebView`. But how can I get the result from that function.

Is there any preferred way using cordova in this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: what kind of native-to-javascript communication are you looking for? Javascript in cordova is used pretty much the same as with the usual apps. It has device ready and some other stuff, but otherwise... ?

Comment: Suppose in javascript there is a function like below which returns some value.  ex: function myFunction(p1, p2) {
    return p1 * p2;              // The function returns the product of p1 and p2
}                 so my question is how can i call this function from cordovaWebview and catch the result at native side.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly get a result from loadUrl. You can expose a Javascript interface using the WebView, see this page for details:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)

Note that the Java methods that Javascript will call *can* return a value, so the communication only has to be asynchronous one way around.

Answer (score 0):

use the code below to get ur work done..

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

                @Override
                public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url,
                        String message, JsResult result) {

                    // use message obj to get the result return by someFunction() function..
                    result.confirm();
                    return true;
                }
            });

            webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(someFunction())");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  but this is a work around , i am looking a way that any preferred way given by cordova.

Comment: @karthik there must me some alternative way for cordova also.. what u have to do to fulfill ur need is to get result in a variable in javascript and return it to some callback function...